# Which is best serach technique to search records

Tags: php, mysql, text, full-text-search

I have 10,000,000 records which will be the best technique to search records, currently i m using full text search but it is slow,please suggest.

Comment: please give some more information and code (about your table structure)

Comment: Give us more details: What are you search for, how often and how these records look like? -- Simply -- give us some examples, please.

Comment: consider a case of database with five tables and i m seraching on one table only with 100 columns and 20 of them are indexed for full text.

all the columns values are text values and changes frequently.hope this will help the gurus(you all). :)

Answer (score 7):

There is no one-size-fits-all solution but you can try out:

**Sphinx**

> How do you implement full-text search
>   for that 10+ million row table, keep
>   up with the load, and stay relevant?
>   Sphinx is good at those kinds of
>   riddles.
>
> Sphinx is a full-text search engine,
>   distributed under GPL version 2.
>   Commercial license is also available
>   for embedded use.
>
> Generally, it's a standalone search
>   engine, meant to provide fast,
>   size-efficient and relevant fulltext
>   search functions to other
>   applications. Sphinx was specially
>   designed to integrate well with SQL
>   databases and scripting languages.
>   Currently built-in data sources
>   support fetching data either via
>   direct connection to MySQL or
>   PostgreSQL, or using XML pipe
>   mechanism (a pipe to indexer in
>   special XML-based format which Sphinx
>   recognizes).
>
> As for the name, Sphinx is an acronym
>   which is officially decoded as SQL
>   Phrase Index. Yes, I know about CMU's
>   Sphinx project.

http://www.sphinxsearch.com/

```
Lucene PHP (Part of Zend Framework):
```

> Zend_Search_Lucene is a general
>   purpose text search engine written
>   entirely in PHP 5. Since it stores its
>   index on the filesystem and does not
>   require a database server, it can add
>   search capabilities to almost any
>   PHP-driven website. Zend_Search_Lucene
>   supports the following features:
>
> - Ranked searching - best results    returned first
> - Many powerful query types: phrase    queries, boolean queries, wildcard
>     queries, proximity queries, range
>     queries and many others.
> - Search by specific field (e.g.,    title, author, contents)

http://framework.zend.com/
http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.search.lucene.overview.html

Comment: +1 for suggesting Zend_Lucene. Never used it with so much items, but never had performance problems with it.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on several simple questions:

- what kind of data is processed? (simple entries like "Firstname, Lastname" or more complex datasets?
- how is it structured? (plain database table? partitioned?)
- what do you search for? (i.e. search for names in telephone directory)

Answer (score 0):

Because i didn't worked with such a large datasets like this here are some ideas that may work:

First question is that these records are static (geoip's for example) or not?

- I'd try to optimize my database as much as i can (try using [EXPLAIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html) if you're using MySQL)
- Look out for every kind of queries that can be possible, try to optimize your database against these queries
- If indexes are fine i'll go with some kind of cache where i would save my previous resultsets. This will be handy when your database isn't updated regulary.
- You can cron the job above (for example: most used search queries and their results can be precached too)
- Try to optimize these ideas for your needs

If you can provide some more details maybe i can refine my tips.

Comment: These are very helpfull techs thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use [**Solr**](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/) . It's lucene with some additions easily accessible by http protocol. It's blazing fast in comparison to any full text searches from mysql.