# Search in huge table

Tags: sql, lucene

I got table with over 1 millions rows.
This table represents user information, e.g userName, email, gender, marrial status etc.

I'm going to write search over all rows in this table, when some conditions are applied.

In simples case, when search is perfomed only on userName, it takes over 4-7 seconds to find result.

```
select from u where u.name ilike " ... "
```

Yes, i got indexes over some fileds. I checked that they are applied using explain analyse command.

How search can be boost ?

I heart something about Lucene, can it help ?

I'm wondering how does Facebook search working, they got billions users and their search works much faster.

Comment: actually Facebook has just over 500 million active users, http://www.facebook.com/press/info.php?statistics

Comment: What flavour of database are you using at the moment? I'd guess PostgreSQL from the use of ilike.

Comment: you need to post more info about your DB setup, 4-7 secs for even 10 mill rows seems really slow. I think you're still missing something in your DB setup, unless you are running on a 486 or have 10MB ethernet or someother bottle neck in your system. Good Luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is great difference between these three queries:

```
a) SELECT * FROM u WHERE u.name LIKE "George%"

b) SELECT * FROM u WHERE u.name LIKE "%George"

c) SELECT * FROM u WHERE u.name LIKE "%George%"
```

---

a) The first will use the index on u.name (if there is one) and will be very fast.

---

b) The second will not be able to use any index on u.name but there are ways to circumvent that rather easily.

For example, you could add another field `nameReversed` in the table where `REVERSE(name)` is stored. With an index on that field, the query will be rewritten as (and will be as fast as the first one):

```
b2) SELECT * FROM u WHERE u.nameReversed LIKE REVERSE("%George")
```

---

c) The third query poses the greatest difficulty as neither of the two previous indexes will be of any help and the query will scan the whole table. Alternatives are:

Using a dedicated for such problems solution (search for "full text search"), like Sphinx. See this question on SO with more details: [which-is-best-search-technique-to-search-records](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3147266/which-is-best-serach-technique-to-search-records)

If your field has names only (or another limited set of words, say a few hundred different words), you could create another auxilary table with those names (words) and store only a foreign key in table `u`.

If off course that is not the case and you have tens of thousands or millions different words or the field contains whole phrases, then to solve the problem with many auxilary tables, it's like creating a full text search tool for yourself. It's a nice exercise and you won't have to use Sphinx (or other) besides the RDBMS but it's not trivial.

Comment: It's not actually true, select with preceding % in ILIKE can use indexes, i read in documentation and tested myself. At least in Postgres. Anyway i accept your answer, since it is the most voluminous.  Probably best solution in this case to use Lucene or Sphinx.

Comment: I didn't know that (*preceding % in ILIKE can use indexes*). Can you provide reference to documentation for this behaviour of Postgres?

Comment: I'm sorry, you are completely right. Just checked documentation, don't even know why i was thinking the opposite.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at 
**Hibernate Search**
this is using Lucene but a lot more easier to implement.

Google or Facebook are using different approaches. They have distributed systems. Googles BigTable is a good keyword or the "Map and Reduce" concept (Apache Hadoop) is a good starting point for more research.

Comment: As far as i know map reduce is not for online searching. Hadopp is used for large dataset analize, map reduce jobs take too many time and ussually works as background tasks

Comment: you have to index too, not only to search. And for distributed systems you need a good base for that, and thats what hadoop is doing. But fore sure thats out of scope for the original question, I just mentioned it, because Google and other big ones have "other" approaches which are not a easy solution to implement in one day.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use table partitioning.
In large table scenarios can be helpful to partiton a table.
For PostgreSQL try here [PostgreSQL Partitioning](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/ddl-partitioning.html).
For high scalable fast performance searches, sometimes may be useful to adopt [NoSQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NoSQL_%28concept%29) database (like Facebook does).

Answer (score 1):

> I heart something about Lucene, can it help ?

Yes, it can. I'm sure, you will love it!

I had the same problem: An table with round about 1.2 Million Messages. By searching trough these Messages it needs some seconds. An full text search on the "message" column needs about 10 seconds.

At the same server hardware lucene returns the result in about 200-400ms.

That's very fast.

Cached results returns in round about 5-10 ms.

Lucene is able to connect to your SQL database (for example mysql) - scans your database an builds an searchable index.

For searching this index it depends on the kind of application.
I my case, my PHP Webaplication uses solr for searching inside lucene.
http://lucene.apache.org/solr/